# Laravel: Create middleware for Sociailite Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, laravel-middleware

I'm using JavaScript to receive an access token to the user facebook account.

When I get the token, I send a request to the server with the token to get information about the user using [Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite).

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->userFromToken($request->token);
        return $user->getName();
```

Now I'm trying to group API calls that only authenticated user can make, for example `/my-profile`, `my-data`, etc...

The middleware purpose is to check if the user is authenticated for a group of API calls instead typing the same condition in all methods:

```
if ($user->getName()) {
...Execute...
}
```

Any idea how I can place the following condition for a list of routes for autehnticated users?

My condition is simple:

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->userFromToken($request->token);
if ($user->getName()) {
return true;
}
else { return false; }
```

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
First create the middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware name_of_your_middleware
```

After that, inside the middleware file that has been created:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
         $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->userFromToken($request->token);

         if ($user->getName()) {
           return $next($request);
         }
         return redirect('some_other_route_for_error');            
    }
```

Then assign the middleware to the routes middelware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
     //.......
    'name_of_your_middleware' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
];
```

In your Route file (api.php):

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['name_of_your_middleware']],function(){
    //your routes
});
```

Hope it helps :)